# Is $GL(E)$ dense in $L(E)$, when $\dim E=\infty$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-algebras

Let $E$ be a normed vector space (Banach space, if you like).

Is $GL(E)$, the set of invertible and continuous endomorphism of $E$, dense in $L(E)$, the set of continuous endomorphism of $E$?

I specify that I know the answer if $dim(E)<\infty$, with classical arguments about the spectrum of matrices, and, I know that $GL(E)$ is open in $L(E)$, even if $dim(E)=\infty$ (if $E$ is a Banach space), using the formula $(I-u)^{-1}=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}u^n$ for $u$ small enough.

So the remaining question I would like to ask is about the density of $GL(E)$ in $L(E)$, and in the case it is not, about its closure.

Comment: Searching a bit results in: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92079/closure-of-the-invertible-operators-on-a-banach-space

Comment: Thanks, couldn't find it, though I assure you I tried... (sorry, a bit new to this, I guess I don't master the research process yet)

Comment: Use google (and add «site:math.stackexchange.com» to your search to restrict results to ones in this site)

Answer (score 5):

For all classical infinite-dimensional Banach spaces invertible operators are not dense but there are instances when they are.

In a Banach algebra, invertible elements are dense if and only if left-invertible elements are dense and if this is so, left-invertible elements are already invertible. However, in the case of classical Banach spaces you always have non-invertible, left invertible elements (for example, isomorphisms onto subspaces of codimension 1).

This is explained in detail in Section 4.2 of my article with Sz. Draga, [*When is multiplication in a Banach algebra open?*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.08608.pdf)